# Character encoding is not updated correctly when update on SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, unicode, utf-8, character-encoding

I updated a record in SQL Server 2014 using the following script:

```
update Contact
set LastName = 'Czapiński'
where id = 2
```

But when I check the database after updating, I can only see the value for `LastName` as `'Czapinski'`. How can I do this update correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to `update` like this

```
update Contact
set LastName = N'Czapiński'
where id = 2
```

with select statements i will show how output will be

```
select N'Czapiński'
o/p---Czapiński
select 'Czapiński'
o/p---Czapinski
```

Comment: What is the meaning of N? How is it possible to use with the Insert statements with Variables?

Comment: @chenk varchar()  will not store and convert  non unique code characters
while passing  with N it will convert to nvarchar() datatype and store that string 
Before updating lastname column convert datatype varchar() to nvarchar() then only the column will  update